# html2canvas not rendering inline base64 background-image in internet explorer

Tags: html2canvas

html2canvas not rendering inline base64 svg background-image in internet explorer, what should i do? i didn't find any solution, it is perfectly working in google chrome and Firefox but not in internet explorer, Kindly help me to sort out this issue.

```
 <div id="demo1">
<h1>data1</h1>
<label id="plate_top" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255); background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; padding: 0px 80px 0px 70px;"></label>
</div>
<div id="preview"></div>
var element = jQuery("#demo1");                    
                    html2canvas(element, {
                    useCORS: true,
                    allowTaint: false,
                    letterRendering: true,
                    logging:true,
                     onrendered: function (canvas) {
                            jQuery("#preview").append(canvas);                 
                     }
                    });
```

Comment: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/274- check this one, may be it's browser issue...

Comment: i checked above link, but what should i do to solve this issue?
and its perfectly working in other browser, which approach have to follow for ie?

Comment: That's the issue mate, you have to wait until someone resolve this, Internet Explorer always a headache for web developers, can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue while trying to import some country flags within an PDF. Everything works fine in chrome and firefox but got issues while trying to import the same flags in PDF using IE11. I have class flag-icon with flag-icon- which translates into an background-image url to an svg on my local server.